# How to change background color of modal presentation ios13?

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

In `iOS 13` we have new modal presentation behavior like this:

[image]

How to change background `.black` color?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That color is the background color of your window. So, assuming that you have a reference to it, the example below:

```
window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

would produce:

[image]